# 'Cutting' type in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is there a way, using the Scissors tool, to cut type into pieces within InDesign? I've converted said type to outlines, but when I use the Scissors tool I'm only able to bend existing points. Below is a video that shows the process I'm taking.

Thanks for any help.

https://vimeo.com/108160992

Comment: Your video says not found.

Comment: Are you limited to the scissors tool? I find it a drag (so to speak) to work with. Have you tried (1) masking, and/or (2) using the path finder?

Comment: I discovered path finder. Find it funny now I even considered the scissors tool after realizing what path finder is for. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the path finder.

Here's a link to an article on slicing and some basic how-to's describing both methods and their functionality.

http://smallbusiness.chron.com/slice-indesign-47519.html